# JQuery UI: Pros and Cons?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've recently been working on streamlining my website and leaning up my HTML and Javascript. I've already begun replacing the MS Ajax.Net JavaScript on my site with jQuery JavaScript, and now I'm looking at some of the html I'm using for things like popups, tab controls, and buttons.

JQuery UI was brought to my attention a few weeks ago and I've been studying it for a while but I'm afraid to jump right into it. I like the theming and I like that it uses "[sprite" like CSS magic](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) for icons. But I've noticed the CSS rounded corners don't work in IE.

So I'm wondering, have/do any of you currently use jQuery UI? If so, what parts are you using? Have you customized it any? What are some pros and cons you've run into?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Incidentally, I started using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) today for the first time :) I am only new to jQuery, but I've dealt with enough JavaScript and other frameworks (prototype, scriptaculous, etc..) to know whats going on.

jQuery is extremely easy to use. Built-in functions are very comprehensive. Compatibility is good. They support most things even in IE6, with the help of plugins.

I've experimented with most of the [common UI elements](http://docs.jquery.com/UI) - dialog, accordion, tabs, and some UI effects, animation, fading and stuff. The fact that it took me less than 1 working day to find out about all these and play with them and also implement them in my current website speaks for the [very small/short learning curve](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page). ([also see this](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials))

Theming is easier than any framework I've seen. They have a nice and easy-to-use theme-builder called [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). Changing CSS by hand is almost unnecessary. You can simply change everything using the WYSIWYG editor and download your edited theme. That is going close to professional ($$$) apps!

Very light-weight - ~19KB. Unlike some other monstrous frameworks I've come across.

Haven't run into any problems, yet... obviously. Been using it only for a day. But from experience (first day with a new framework never went this smoothly for me :)), I am not expecting many problems.

Comment: I'm going to choose your answer, because it was the most informative, I sort of wish I could choose two, because Noseredna's post was also extremely interesting and helpful.

Answer (score 3):

One of the nicest things from jQuery.UI I think is the widget factory, which gives you a quick way of creating your own plug-ins.

check it out : [UI_Developer_Guide](http://docs.jquery.com/UI_Developer_Guide)

Comment: That is pretty cool, now that I look at it. Doesn't seem very straight forward at first, but I think that's more because of weak examples on the site. I'll ahve to play with it a bit.

Comment: Is there a repository of plugins using this widget factory?

Comment: I meant besides those. Any 3rd party?

Comment: I found this. I wonder when these start rolling out to become official supported widgets... http://wiki.jqueryui.com/browse/#view=ViewFolder&param=All%20Plugins%3A%20designs%20and%20specs.

Answer (score 2):

I've only used [UI Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) from the group. It works great in all browsers expect of IE8. It consumed [100% CPU](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4758) when using `modal:true`. After outcommenting the following line it works like a charm:

```
$(window).bind('resize.dialog-overlay', $.ui.dialog.overlay.resize);
```

You can if necessary add an `if (!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version >= 8))` to the particular line. The bugfix seems to be targeted on 1.8.

From the remaining of the UI components I didn't have any need to use any of them. I also didn't have a strong feeling of a robust library after checking the [bugs](http://dev.jqueryui.com/report/1). The guys are certainly working well on that, it will certainly improve in the future, but as far now it isn't well-polished enough to me yet to use in production.

Comment: What version of jquery ui are you using that that bug occurred with? (just wondering if it's been fixed)

Comment: OMG, 3 months ago it was `BalusC` who resolved this bug :o,  `+1 toh banta hai` ;) i mean, he should get a +1 now

Comment: @blesh: I've posted a link and I also said that fix is targeted on 1.8 (which thus implies that all of the older versions may suffer from the particular bug).

Comment: @BalusC : I implemented the Dialog in my website today. The only problem I found in IE8 was, scrollbars appeared in the window. Even that appeared only when I set it as 'modal' and the overlay appeared, due to some width/height discrepancy. Without the overlay, even that problem wasn't there. My CPU was doing just fine. Im wondering why it was working like that in your system!

Comment: The bug only reveals if you're using `modal:true`. Or you've a multiCPU/multiCore machine. Also see the link to bug report.

Comment: As I said, I AM using modal:true - the overlay is coming for me. That is when the scrollbar problem comes, not the 100% CPU usage problem. Also, my machine HAS a multi core (2) processor. Weird! I'll check the link anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you're starting from scratch, I suggest you take a peek at ExtJS also.

I like JQuery, but I found one too many UI plugins to be buggy.  Since ExtJS has fewer third party plugins - and I typically find what ExtJS provides is adequate - I have fewer problems with ExtJS.  Since I like the low level DOM manipulation capabilities of JQuery, I usually use it "underneath" ExtJS.

Comment: interesting I'll have a look.

Comment: Seems like ExtJS is a little more geared toward intranet app type stuff, whereas I'm developing an e-commerce site.

Comment: Fair enough; and you can't go wrong with JQuery.

Comment: It does look pretty cool though, and I'll keep it in mind for more "applicationy" sites.

Answer (score 2):

I used it a year ago. If one of the widgets fits your needs, that's great. I like the Themeroller.

But, overall, I wasn't thrilled with jQueryUI and I wouldn't use it again. Several small things bugged me until the cumulative feeling was displeasure. I had to fight the model dialog. The accordion animation is jumpy in some browsers. In at least a few of the widgets, there is no difference between the UI's hover state and its depressed state.

Example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ At least in the Chrome browser I'm running now, the animation problems with this demo actually cause scroll bars to appear during the animation.

I don't understand why there haven't been any widgets added in at least a year.

I think a lot of my disappoint with jQueryUI comes from how much I like jQuery and what I expect from an official widget library associated with it.

Comment: If you no longer use it, what do you use now? Something home-brew?

Comment: That's a great question and I'm always looking around. Right now I just look for jQuery plugins. But I might take another look at YUI and investigate Google Closure. The ExtJS stuff looks good, but I don't like the license.

Comment: I tested the accordion in both version of Chrome I had and didn't see the problem you're describing. What version of Chrome are you running?

Comment: I am up to date with 4.0.223.16. But it's not just Chrome. If you keep your eye on "Section 4" while clicking other sections, you'll see Section 4 move up and down during the animation. Many Browsers. And in Adobe AIR's webkit as well. I just tested Safari and saw the scroll bars pop in and out of existence as well. Much more stable in FF. The Section 4 bar stays rock solid (but the text inside jitters sometimes).

Comment: Very much weird movement in IE8 as well.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'm still tossed up. In your experience does it seem like it's JQuery UI or JQuery's animation stuff that's causing the jittery behavior?

Comment: And just tried it on both Safari and Chrome beta for the Mac. Scroll bars flash off and on. I believe this is a side-effect of the vertical instability of the accordion during animation.

Comment: @blesh, I've not looked at the code, but I'd guess that it's a subtlety in jQuery's scroll coming through. I'm not assigning blame. It's just that my experience with jQueryUI was full of these "doesn't feel solid" moments that I kept working around.

Answer (score 1):

I have used JQuery Datepicker and some of the other UI modules along with using JQuery for the most parts of my project.

- It is completely customizable, which makes it easy to modify according to your convenience.
- Basically jQuery is light weight and is also programmer friendly to write scripts in an elegant way.
- I tweaked more on the styling part rather than on functionality to achieve the desired look and feel.

I didn't find anything negative about it till now, may be in future when I use some more of JQuery UI modules

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, congratulations on switching to jQuery.  It's an incredible javascript library and if you're like me you'll love it.

I'm using the UI on several sites, which I mostly like for just grabbing a customized UI build to suite my need.

I predominantly use it for the datepicker and sortables and haven't run into any issues. I find them to be very easily customized if you understand how to use jQuery.

Hope that helps a little bit - enjoy!