# YUI - Pros and Cons

Tags: javascript, css, frameworks, yui

I'm about to begin a new project and plan to use YUI and my JS and CSS framework for the following reasons:

1. Treeview with tri-state checkboxes (seems to be the best implementation I could find)
2. Calandar (seen others, but since #1 is on YUI, I'm glad it also has calendar)
3. CSS framework (was going to use 960, but might as well go 100% Yahoo)

I plan to use only 1 JS framework.

Does anyone see any problems with my decision?

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841603/jquery-ui-pros-and-cons/1841666#1841666

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YUI is simple, easy to use, with very good examples, a very useful user group and developers who respond quickly and to the object. I have used it successfully in a few projects, including one where I had to extend the calendar to support week and month selection.

If you are comfortable with YUI and you think the components you need are best implemented there, I don't see why you wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want support for your choice of javascript libraries, this might be telling:

Stack Overflow tags:

- yui × 335
- prototype × 673
- extjs × 327
- jquery × 17136

Comment: But what does it tell? That jQuery is hard to use and that lots of people have problems with it? That YUI has such a good support system of its own that YUI users don't come to SO with their problems?

By themselves, the numbers are meaningless.

Comment: I agree. The tag count isn't an indicator of whether or not my decision to use YUI is a good decision.

Has anyone seen a JQuery treeview that supports tri-state checkboxes?

Comment: I also agree. I've used YUI in the past and although I find the SO community extraordinary, there is not one question which was not answered for me on the YUI usergroup - that is where I would ask first.

Comment: As an interested observer, I've noticed that YUI users are much more active on our forums (http://yuilibrary.com/forum/) than they are here on StackOverflow.  That's the first place you want to go when you need help with a YUI-related question.

Answer (score 2):

I have used YUI for a long time, and highly recommend it.
 - It's very well documented
 - The YUI forum is great for getting answers
 - The code is very well written, very easy to pick the components you want/need (even easier with YUI 3), and not download the whole framework
 - A very feature-rich set of widgets (calendar, treeview, carousel, autocomplete, etc)
 - When reporting a bug to the developers you quickly get a reply
 - The fact that YAHOO use it themselves on their own highly trafficked sites should give you some extra confidence that it will perform well, and be supported for a long time...

I also find this article to be very true, using YUI has without a doubt improved my javascript skills. A lot!
http://foohack.com/2007/08/yui-crockford-module-pattern-vs-prototypes-class-function/

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I really like [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/). Most of the links are from YUI2, but they are also working hard on YUI3.

### Pros:

1. A lot of [documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/2/). The quality of the documentation is also pretty good. It is sometimes a lot of documentation you have to read(not really necessary if one of the examples does what you need).
2. A lot of [code examples](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/). Which you can play with immediately.
3. Good javascript [API](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/).
4. Has a [CDN](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/hosting/) which hosts there library for you. This can significantly improve performance because. I also would like to notice that YAHOO's CDN [combo's files](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/07/17/yuis-combo-handler-cdn-service/) which is another big boost for performance. This used to be a big pro for me, but now google also hosted the most influatential libraries for you so this isn't such a big pro as it was to me anymore(I still like that they combo javascript files).
5. [active open source development](http://github.com/yui)(If you like you can contribute yourself via github) by a lot of really good javascript programmers. For example: Douglas Crockford, Eric Miraglia, [and a lot more](http://github.com/yui/yui3/network/members).

### Cons:

1. Sometimes a little verbose(YUI2) but in YUI3 they have improved this in my opinion not really a con. Also a lot of users liked the verbose syntax (I liked it most of the times).

### Verdict:

- Overall YUI is really a good
  javascript library if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a fair amount of experience with YUI already, I'd suggest having a try with JQuery.  It is well supported and easy to learn and use.

Comment: So is YUI — it also meets the requirements listed in the question.  WatiNNewbie repeated the need for a tri-state checkbox supporting treeview in a comment, and noone has pointed to a jQuery implementation yet.